# Пытаюсь реализовать проверку даты на Javascript, если введена текущая дата или больше ошибка если меньше все ОК. прошу подскажите как это сделать

Tags: javascript

```
function validDate(value)
{
    var arrD = value.split(".");
    arrD[1] -= 1;
    var d = new Date(arrD[2]+'.'+ arrD[1]+'.'+ arrD[0]+'');
        if ((d.getFullYear() == arrD[2]) && (d.getMonth() == arrD[1]) && (d.getDate() == arrD[0])) 
        {
            return true;
        } 
            else 
            {
            alert("Введена некорректная дата!");
            return false;
            }
}
```

Comment: в каком формате вводится дата?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычное условие:

```js
function validDate() {
  const inputDate = new Date(document.getElementById('inputDate').value).toISOString().slice(0, 10); // введенная дата (обрезанная до год-месяц-день)
  const currentDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10); // текущая дата (обрезанная до год-месяц-день)
  const res = (inputDate < currentDate); // сравниваем...
  (res) ? alert('ок') : alert('не ок'); // выводим ок или не ок
  return res; // возвращаем true или false
}
```

```html
<input id="inputDate" type="date" value="2019-02-01" required /><button onclick="validDate()">Проверить</button>
```

Без кнопки:

```js
function validDate(val) {
  const inputDate = new Date(val).toISOString().slice(0, 10); // введенная дата (обрезанная до год-месяц-день)
  const currentDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10); // текущая дата (обрезанная до год-месяц-день)
  const res = (inputDate < currentDate); // сравниваем...
  (res) ? alert('ок') : alert('не ок'); // выводим ок или не ок
  return res; // возвращаем true или false
}
```

```html
<input type="date" value="2019-02-01" onblur="validDate(this.value)" required />
```

Comment: у меня реализация без кнопки (( нужно проверку на поле сделать

Comment: @ПетрГагарский Тогда ещё проще) Добавил код выше

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! ща сяду повчитываюсь в методолгию проверки! подскажите еще пожалуйста: как сделать чтобы проверка onchange начала выполнятся после полного ввода даты(имею ввиду год(срабатывает после первого разжатия клавиши))

Comment: @ПетрГагарский можете вместо `onchange` поставить `onblur`, например. Тогда функция будет запускаться каждый раз при потере фокуса, что даст ввести дату полностью.

Comment: Оо я читал про onblur но видимо не понял правильно!!

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо за помощь не знаю как и благодарить!!!)))) как вас можно отблагодарить?! =)

Comment: @ПетрГагарский Спасибо. Да никак, рад был помочь! Успехов в освоении :)