# Как проверить дату на существование?

Tags: javascript

под существованием имеется ввиду не 10.52.2022

(формат 10.06.2022 приходит с инпута)
и чтобы она была не больше, чем сегодня

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/946580/%D0%9F%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-javascript-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B1 думаю поможет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date вернёт `null` если дата неверная, а ещё сверяем timestamp текущей даты с переданной, если переданная дата не будет `null` и меньше текущей, то функция вернёт `true`.

```js
function CheckDate(str) {
  str = str.split('.').reverse();
  let cur = new Date();
  let date = new Date(str);
  
  cur.setHours(0,0,0,0); // обнулим время
  
  return date !== null && date.getTime() > cur.getTime();
}

console.info('10.99.2022', CheckDate('10.99.2022'));
console.info('40.06.2022', CheckDate('40.06.2022'));
console.info('10.06.2025', CheckDate('10.06.2025'));
```