# Как сравнить две даты?

Tags: javascript

даты в формате 12.06.2022
и 11.06.2022

первая всегда должна быть больше, чем вторая

Answer (score 0):

Я писал вам [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1419069/221218), там сверяются две даты, всего лишь нужно подставить ваши значения:

```js
let dateA = '12.06.2022';
let dateB = '11.06.2022';

// Т.к. new Date(); принимает данные в формате YYYY/MM/DD, то проще всего будет разделить строку по точкам и развернуть получившийся массив
let a = dateA.split('.').reverse();
let b = dateB.split('.').reverse();

// Далее создаём Date
a = new Date(a);
b = new Date(b);

// Вернём даты в миллисекундах (timestamp)
a = a.getTime();
b = b.getTime();

//Проверяем, a > b
console.info(`${dateA} > ${dateB}? - ${a > b}`);
```

Или в сравнение в качестве функции:

```js
let dateA = '12.06.2022';
let dateB = '11.06.2022';

function DateAMoreB(a, b) {
  a = a.split('.').reverse();
  b = b.split('.').reverse();

  return new Date(a).getTime() > new Date(b).getTime();
}

console.info(`${dateA} > ${dateB}? - ${DateAMoreB(dateA, dateB)}`);
console.info(`${dateB} > ${dateA}? - ${DateAMoreB(dateB, dateA)}`);
```